# Android SDK Manager Not Responding Mac

Tags: android, macos, command-line-interface, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

this is not a problem with my path, as I can start the manager with the command "android" from command prompt, but the issue is that once it starts it appears in the dock, then no window shows up and it goes to not responding. I have tried with both opening it from the command line and Android Studio, both wielding the same results.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if you have installed JDK and JRE?

Comment: I am, I'm able to use use the "Java" command in command line and build cordova apps.